# Jquery in Wordpress not running

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use the following to create a small thumbnail gallery:

This is the code I'm using:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gkjx2/

It's obviously running in jsfiddle but not in my webpage, can anyone work out what's going wrong?

Comment: Try using the full name `$jQuery` instead of `$` abbreviate version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
jQuery('.showImg').hover(function(){    


    var imgURL = jQuery(this).find('img').attr("src");    
    jQuery('#imgHolder').find('img').attr("src", imgURL);    
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors on the page and there is no ".active" on your web site.

**EDIT**

Make sure your code is parallel.  Your fiddle is working since the code is there, but not on your web site.

Ok, your fiddle has an img tag, but you don't have one in there in your site...  Thats what I mean by parallel, you're searching for something nonexistent with .find().

Fiddle:

```
<div id="imgHolder">
    <img src="http://www.whitegadget.com/attachments/pc-wallpapers/16215d1222951905-nature-photos-wallpapers-images-beautiful-pictures-nature-444-photos.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="400">        
</div>
```

Site:

```
<div id="imgHolder">
</div>
```

Here's what your fiddle should look like:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gkjx2/1/

Your issue is the js is using find to find an img tag in the imgHolder, but there isn't one so nothing happens.  I suggest adding the the first image you load.

Comment: I've removed the active part for now.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, adding the image in the fiddle works but trying that on my site doesn't work. Something is clashing with it.

Comment: you have a typo `?` on your script.

Comment: Sorry that was me just pasting back in some code just now. It's definitely something in the jQuery that's not triggering or clashing with the Wordpress setup now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: jQuery is included twice

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.neurosignsurgical.com/v2/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2"></script>
```

Remove one and update the other to the newest version because both are outdated.

Second of all, I can't seem to find your code anywhere.

And third: in this case it's better to use `children` than `find`. Performance-wise it will be faster.

Comment: If you view the source it starts on 168.

Comment: You should load jQuery BEFORE running any other script. Also, why would you place your JS code in the middle of your document? I know it's done sometimes by plug-ins, but in this case it's all but necessary. And lastly: as far as I know $jQuery isn't a correct prefix. `$` is and `jQuery` is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Wordpress, but maybe it's using other js-libs?
in that case your $ is probably in use.

Try to use jQuery(stuff) instead of $(stuff) with jQuery.noConflict(); on top of your script

Comment: A quick look at the page would teach you that jQuery is included.